# Dynamic active class in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, navigation

I have a number of li's in my menu

```
<li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=='user'|| 'role'|| 'sections' || 'actions') {echo 'active open';} else {echo 'noactive';} ?>">
```

It is always in open stage even if controller name not in url, so any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is not right. try this

```
<li class="<?php if(($this->uri->segment(1) == 'user') || ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'role') || ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'sections') || ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'actions')) {echo 'active open';} else {echo 'noactive';} ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you @Rejoanul, but still it is in same condition not closing

Comment: are you getting right class name based on condition? if so then you have CSS issue